# How to delete all columns except first five?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with approximately 90 columns and want to delete all after the 5th. How to delete all columns except first five?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only want to keep a few columns, the option with least code would be to make a new table with those columns only. You should do this [in a transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) to avoid losing data.

Example with two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName RENAME TO TmpTableName;
CREATE TABLE TableName(Col1 INTEGER, Col2 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TableName(Col1, Col2) SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM TmpTableName;
DROP TABLE TmpTableName;
```

Before [version 3.35.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_35_0.html), SQLite did not support removing columns, so this was the only possible option.